# get data from a seperate JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

How can I go about getting data from a second JFrame in java swing?
I have one frame with a JLabel and a JButton. When the JButton is clicked it opens another frame with a custom calendar. I want to select the date (via JButton) and have the date in the JLabel of the main JFrame. I don't want to create a new instance of the first frame, because there is other information that I don't want deleted that the user may type.

Comment: *"seperate JFrame"* See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) The first thing that springs to mind when I see *"get data"* is a `JOptionPane` or a `JDialog` declared to be modal. Do I need to read the question body, or does that info. give you a way to proceed?

Comment: If it just about picking the date then why dont you use existing date pickers. Like this  https://sourceforge.net/projects/jdatepicker/

Comment: @PrashantZombade I want to my make own, that way I have full control over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in many places, using 2 `JFrame`s is not a good practice. Instead of the second `JFrame`, you can use a `JDialog` like in below example.

We can get the user input date using `getDate()` and use it in the frame.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class TwoFrames
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame");

    JLabel label = new JLabel("No date selected");

    JButton button = new JButton("Open date dialog");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
        DateDialog dateDialog = new DateDialog(frame);
        dateDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
        dateDialog.setVisible(true);
        label.setText(dateDialog.getDate());
      }
    });

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.getContentPane().add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.setBounds(300, 200, 400, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}

class DateDialog extends JDialog
{
  private String date;

  DateDialog(Frame owner)
  {
    super(owner, "Select date", true);
    JTextField dateField = new JTextField(20);

    JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
    okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
        date = dateField.getText();
        setVisible(false);
      }
    });

    getContentPane().add(dateField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    getContentPane().add(okButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    setSize(300, 200);
  }

  String getDate()
  {
    return date;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is actually going to lead me in the right direction. So, would I be able to have as many items in a JDialog as I want? With a bunch of buttons?

Comment: @Vince, yes, you can have many components (buttons, labels etc.) inside a JDialog.